# How can I save the response created by my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, zip

There is CSV-export of some objects (such as tasks, contacts, etc) in my application. It just renders CSV-file like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { render text: Task.to_csv } # I have self.to_csv def in model
end
```

It generates a CSV file when I go to '/tasks.csv' without a problem.

Now I want to export all the objects and zip them. I'm using rubyzip gem to create zip-files. Now my code for creating zip-file with all the CSVs looks like that:

```
Zip::ZipFile.open("#{path_to_file}.zip", Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  zipfile.file.open("tasks.csv", "w") { |f| f << open("http://#{request.host}:#{request.port.to_s}/tasks.csv").read }
  # the same lines for contacts and other objects
end
```

But it seems that there is something wrong with it because it's executing for a long time (I'm getting Timeout::Error even if there is just one line in CSV) and the resulting zip-archive contains something broken.

How can I save my "/tasks.csv", "/contacts.csv", etc as a file on server (inside of zip-archive in this case)?

Comment: `f << open("http://...")` The `open` method here is on which object?

Comment: I see that there is something wrong but I don't really know how to fix it. `File.open(...)` returns "no such file" error. Maybe I should use `Net:HTTP` to open that file but I can't make it work as yet, too. I hope there is a way to get this file without http-responses.

Comment: It seems that `Net:HTTP` doesn't work because there is user authentication in my app. So this is another one reason to find a way to do it without http-responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it! The code is:

```
Zip::ZipFile.open("#{path_to_file}.zip", Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zipfile|

  zipfile.file.open("tasks.csv", "w") do |f| 
    CSV.open(f, "w") do |csv|
      CSV.parse(Task.to_csv) { |row| csv << row }
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Don't want to confuse you or anything but isn't a CSV just a text file? Why use CSV module and waste time and CPU? You can just copy the entire file like `File.open(<newfile>, "w") {|f| f.write(File.open(<oldfile>).read)}` However, if you do want to use CSV, better go for FasterCSV which is..erm..faster.

Comment: The whole point is that <oldfile> doesn't exist. It's generated when I get /tasks.csv URL. So, I can't just open it and write it's content to the new file.